# Is multi-class classification the same with categorical classification?

Tags: multiclass-classification

I am working on a project with image classification with 5 different classes and I was wondering if categorical classification can be used as a synonym for multi-class classification.

PS. Forgive me for the naive question

Comment: yes it's the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the answer is as simple as :

- Binary Classification means only 2 targets to find.
- Multilabel / Multiclass / Multinomial Classification means more than 2 targets to find.

In Supervised Learning, you will have :

- Classification (class of 0, 1 etc..)
- Regression (continuous values 84.2, 105.8 etc..)

**Categorical** and **class** means the same and are the opposite of **Regression** which are **continuous variables**

You can find example on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html#supervised-learning